# What are the differences between the perceptron and linear regression hypothesis set?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, perceptron

While studying machine learning I have known 2 learning models: linear regression and perceptron.
I know the difference between the Learning algorithm they use, but the hypothesis set look the same to me.
Are there any difference?